# Video_player Crashes Android Emulator in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-video-player

I am trying to use the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), but I am getting the below error. I have also added an MRE (minimum reproducible example).

I have used an emulated Pixel 4, an emulated Pixel 4 XL, and an emulator Pixel 5 with the Android Studio Beta, but none of them worked.

The below error was when I was using a Pixel 4 XL, but the error was the same with all of them.

Error:

```
~\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Flutter\video_player_not_working> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 64 arm64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software
rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 in debug mode...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 31 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 31 in C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 31 (revision: 1)" finished.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            153.4s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...              2,093ms
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 64 arm64...                 292ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:51217/xDqrRJJJEMY=/
W/yer_not_workin( 5318): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 5318): Init d52da73 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [generic_x86_64_arm64, sdk_gphone_x86_64_arm64, Google, 30]
I/Choreographer( 5318): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/TetheringManager( 5318): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.video_player_not_working
I/VideoCapabilities( 5318): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/OMXClient( 5318): IOmx service obtained
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:51217/xDqrRJJJEMY=/
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): connecting to surface 0x70fcbf3cba60, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec( 5318): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 5445633
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): disconnecting from surface 0x70fcbf3cba60, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): connecting to surface 0x70fcbf3cba60, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
E/ACodec  ( 5318): [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
I/ACodec  ( 5318): codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): disconnecting from surface 0x70fcbf3cba60, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): connecting to surface 0x70fcbf3cba60, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils( 5318): set up nativeWindow 0x70fcbf3cba60 for 1280x720, color 0x13, rotation 0, usage 0x1002900
W/Gralloc4( 5318): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/CCodec  ( 5318): allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
Lost connection to device.
```

`main.dart`:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(const VideoPlayerApp());

class VideoPlayerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const VideoPlayerApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Player Demo',
      home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
    );

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Butterfly Video'),
      ),
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
            // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            );
          } else {
            // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
            // loading spinner.
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
          // correct icon is shown.
          setState(() {
            // If the video is playing, pause it.
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              // If the video is paused, play it.
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`pubspec.yaml`

```
name: video_player_not_working
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  video_player: ^2.2.10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.video_player_not_working">
   <application
        android:label="video_player_not_working"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
~\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Flutter\video_player_not_working> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.376], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\tools\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (2 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                     • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
    • Edge (web)                       • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.62

• No issues found!
```

Comment: the code works on my physical device. but not in my emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a bug of that Flutter package, indeed. Have you tried to create an issue in GitHub of that package?

Secondly, during my development, I see several times when emulators just fail and real devices always work. The solution I used is - simply to do *not* test them on simulators. Real users never use simulators, aren't they?

It can be a bug of the library when running on x86 arch (the arch simulators use). Then, nobody with a real device (arm arch) will ever see the bug.

Thirdly, what about trying to use "cloud real devices" to test whether they work on real Pixel devices that you are worried about. There are many platforms that host some real devices and you can connect to them via a webpage and test your app.

Comment: i have not opened a github issue but I will. I will try to use a real device and see if it works. Because only real users will see the video it makes sense that I would use a real device! Thanks for the help, I will award the bounty if it works with a real device.

Comment: @KetZoomer does it work for you?

Comment: i updated android studio and a few sdk tools and it started working again, I will that as an answer. I have not tested with a real android phone yet

Comment: @KetZoomer sounds great!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue where any video playback on my emulated device(not alone in a Flutter app) would crash and terminate the emulator's process.

To prevent this issue, I did the following:

1. Power off your emulator device.
2. Go to Device Manager in Android Studio.
3. Click on the edit button on your emulator device.
4. Click *Show Advanced Settings* in *Virtual Device Configuration* dialog.
5. In the *Emulated Performance* section, set *Graphics* to *Software - GLES 2.0*, instead of the default *Automatic*.
6. Start your emulator device.

Thre is one caveat though due to switching Graphics to Software, the performance on the emulator device is slow, if the system you are running on is powerful then you wouldn't notice this performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

This Error is not flutter related rather the media support inside the exoplayer itself.

```
I/VideoCapabilities( 5318): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

This shows that the video is streamed from the server is mp4v-es. which is showing that the format is incompatible with the platform android.

This has already been reported to google exo-player on Github.
https://issueexplorer.com/issue/google/ExoPlayer/9388

Seems like this is a live streaming URL and you need to convert them from the server-side for a supported format for both android and IOS video players or you can do on the platform side to resolve this.

Comment: could you give some details on how to do this? and updating a few tools fixed the problem, so it was probably a bug